# using preg_match to check email domain

Tags: php

How can I modify the preg_match function below to allow all email addresses ending with harvard.edu email addresses, instead of only those with @college.harvard.edu?

```
if(!preg_match("/@college\.harvard\.edu$/", $_POST["username"]))
    {
        apologize("You must provide a Harvard email to register.");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(!preg_match("/@.*harvard\.edu$/", $_POST["username"]))
{
    apologize("You must provide a Harvard email address to register.");
}
```